# Error while conda environment creation got stuck

Tags: anaconda, conda

I am trying to create conda environment but it got stuck while collecting meta data not sure how to proceed further

Comment: Please provide verbose err log.

Comment: 'Solving environment' can sometimes take ages especially if a lot of complex dependencies have to be resolved. Can you run other conda commands that access channels successfully e.g. `conda search python`? Please show us the actual command you were trying to execute.